# Mock Bitmap without using PowerMock or how to mock final class

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, android-bitmap

Can any please give suggest a way to mock final class without using PowerMock.
For Example: Please try to mock Bitmap class.

Comment: Please give an example of your code where you are using the Bitmap class

Comment: @Test
public void testCanvas(){
 mCanvas = new Canvas();
 Bitmap bitmap = mock(Bitmap.class); //Here is the problem i can't mock this bitmap as it is final
 mCanvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
 //some other code removed
}

Comment: In that case you need to create a wrapper object that wraps the functionality that you need from Bitmap. eg class BitmapWrapper with Bitmap as a private field. Now, for BitmapWrapper add a function for each method of Bitmap that you want to use. Inside the BitmapWrapper methods, delegate the call to the Bitmap private field methods. The BitmapWrapper can now be used and mocked wherever you need it.

Comment: I found a way here is the link: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-Mockito-2#unmockable

Comment: Thank you for the link, I learned something today!